# In Freemarker is it possible to use the value of a hash item as a method? i.e., ${key}: ${val?val}

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to make a function or macro to test a variable against all Freemarker is_xxxx types (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_isType), so that I can just run a variable through that function/macro to see what it is.

I could obviously just run each one at a time and return that, i.e.,

```
is_string? ${var?is_string?c} <br/>
is_hash? ${var?is_hash?c} <br/>
```

I was hoping to avoid that by `<#list>` ing through a hash, but I couldn't figure it out ... then I just got curious if this sort of thing were even possible.

At a loss how to do this, or if I can.

For example

```
<#assign builtIns = {"is_string":"is_string","is_number":"is_number","is_boolean":"is_boolean","is_date_like":"is_date_like","is_date_only":"is_date_only","is_time time":"is_time time",
"is_datetime":"is_datetime","is_unknown_date_like":"is_unknown_date_like","is_method":"is_method","is_transform":"is_transform","is_macro":"is_macro","is_hash hash":"is_hash hash","is_hash_ex":"is_hash_ex","is_sequence 
sequence":"is_sequence sequence","is_collection":"is_collection","is_collection_ex":"is_collection_ex","is_enumerable":"is_enumerable","is_indexable":"is_indexable","is_directive":"is_directive","is_node
node":"is_node node","is_markup_output":"is_markup_output"}
/>

<#list builtIns as key,val>
    ${key},${val?val} <br/>   // or something like this. 
</#list>
```

Make sense? Possible? A different way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 2):

No, the so called built-ins (things after the `?`) has no value, so you can't put them into variables. That's unlike normal methods, FTL macros, and FTL functions, which can be passed around as a value. The difference is because some built-ins affect template parsing (kind of like compilation), so they are not purely runtime.

Well, you could get around that with generating the expression as a string then do `myExpressionString?eval`, but that's awkward and somewhat slow.